# error while imlpementing search text for the firestore list in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, search, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-listview

I am implementing the below code for the search operation in the list in flutter application for firestore database.

When no search is implemented it loads the list fine, but when I try to use the search operation for the same it gives me error

**ERROR : type 'Query' is not a subtype of type 'Stream'**

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    elevation: 0,
    title:                     Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),

      child: Card(
        child: TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search), hintText: 'Search...'),
          onChanged: (val) {
            setState(() {
              query = val;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),

    ),

    leading: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.exit_to_app,
          color: Colors.red[50],
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          logout();
        }),
  ),
  body:

  Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
             


              Container(
                child: Expanded(
                  child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    stream: (query != "" && query != null)
                        ? FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('momos_nv')
      .orderBy('itemName')
      .startAt([query])
      .endAt([query + '\uf8ff'])
                        : FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("momos_nv").snapshots(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {

                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Text('Something went wrong');
                      }

                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return Text("Loading");
                      }

                      return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index){

                   
                            return ListTile(title:Text(snapshot.data.docs[index]['itemName'],
                            ),
                            );
                          });

                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ));
```

I am not able to resolve it , as am not able to understand where the wrong is happening when the search is done, I have referred any example from GitHub which working fine but when replicating the same it is not working well. Please advise the right implementation for the same.

The error comes I just started typing in the search box.

The example I have referred is this one from Github [referred sample code](https://github.com/flutter-devs/search_feature_demo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Container(
                child: Expanded(
                  child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    stream: (query != "" && query != null)
                        ? FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('momos_nv')
      .orderBy('itemName')
      .startAt([query])
      .endAt([query + '\uf8ff']).snapshots() ----> you have missed the snapShot here
                        : FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("momos_nv").snapshots(),
```

1. You have missed the snapShot on stream if condition
2. Please look the below steam condition to resolve it.